# obtain errors from PHP execution

Tags: php, error-handling

in the same folder I have:
php.ini

```
display_errors  = "stdout"     ; Also tryed: "STDOUT"  0  and  1
```

this info from phpinfo()

```
PHP Version 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.9
display_errors      Off     Off  ;never changes no matter what I put in php.ini
error_reporting   22527   22527
```

and this test.php script

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo "start test<br>";
typoErr();
echo "never here<br>";
?>
```

I have tested alternatives and I cant find the way to see errors on the browser.

Comment: did you restart your web server (probably apache httpd) after changing php.ini?

Comment: Did you edit the right `php.ini`?

Comment: @KingCrunch I have created a php.ini file on document_root and on a subfolder of it

Comment: what system are you on? windows? linux? mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also add

```
php_flag display_errors on
```

To apache's sites-available or htacess

Just remember to restart apache

Comment: actualy it was my final solution. but no need to restart editint on .htaccess

Answer (score 3):

probabily you're editing the wrong php.ini
try use `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the very beginning of test.php
it should overwrite your ini configs.

Comment: great, I can see the error in this way. but I am wondering: witch is the "correct" php.ini I put a copy of it on the document_root (the parent folder of my test folder) but nothing changes, I cant obtain the error.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from the comments:

> @KingCrunch I have created a php.ini file on document_root and on a subfolder of it

You can not assume, that the interpreter will just use *any* `php.ini`. Look at the output of `phpinfo()`. Somewhere at the beginning there is noted, which `php.ini` you must use. Remember to restart the webserver after every change and that the cli-interpreter usually takes another `php.ini` than the interpreter used by the webserver (`php -i` is the cli equivalent of `phpinfo()`)..

Comment: thanks, all this configurations bring to the light
`Configuration File (php.ini) Path` 
`Loaded Configuration File` 
`Scan this dir for additional .ini files` 
`Additional .ini files parsed`
none of my edited php.ini(s) were on this pointed paths

Comment: Thats the point: You just edit the wrong one(s) ;) You can edit the file specified by `Loaded Configuration File`, or you put an own `*.ini`-file into `Scan this dir for additional .ini files`.